# How to enable VT-x for a windows 7 guest running on KVM on RHEL

Tags: virtualization, kvm

to run the emulator in the new Android Develop Studio, I need to turn on the virtualization support (VT-x) on my guest windows 7 running in KVM, which in turn is on RHEL6.
Google shows we need vmx & vme in the guest processor definition, which I have them as 'require' from dumpxml. But in Android Develop Studio in my guest win7, it still complains about missing virtualization support.
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
I then download 'haxm-windows_r05' and run 'intelhaxm.exe' to install it, with error:
VT not supported
This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). HAXM cannot be installed.
Please refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.

In summary, my guest (windows 7) on KVM (running on RHEL 6) can not turn on Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x).

Thanks for any help

Andy

Comment: have you confirmed that virtualization is enabled in the host system? egrep ‘vmx’ /proc/cpuinfo

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, RHEL6 lacks support for Nested Virtualization. RHEL7 does but it's still very premature and new changes keep getting added. Your best bet is to install the current upstream kernel. To enable Nested Virtualization, load kvm_intel with "modprobe kvm_intel nested=1".

And ofcourse, you need to advertise vmx in your cpu definition.

Comment: I have similar problem (RHEL 7.2 with Win 7 as guest) as one originally reported. Any idea how I can > advertize vmx in cpu definition?